# Stretch arrays in dataframe to all be the same size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, interpolation

I have a dataframe called allData with thousands of rows of participant data, where each row contains: a single trial's participant number (single value) and a numpy array of x,y trajectory data (always 2 columns, but ranges from 100-900 rows in length).
The dataframe allData looks like this:

```
   participantNum   data
0         6432024  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-15.83345, 5.0],...
1         1039607  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
2         6950203  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
3         8486566  [[-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], ...
4         1315866  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
5         8593676  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
6         9526582  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
7         6432024  [[-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-16.0, 5.0], [-1...
8         9719645  [[-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], ...
9         7830381  [[-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], [-16.0, -5.0], ...
```

And if I isolate one of allData's row's x,y data with: XY = allData.iloc[1].data, it looks something like this:

```
   [-16.        ,   5.        ],
   [-15.8315    ,   5.        ],
   [-15.6705    ,   5.        ],
   [-15.5039    ,   5.        ],
   [-15.3373    ,   5.        ],
   [-15.1691    ,   5.        ],
   [-14.8319    ,   5.        ],
   [-14.671     ,   5.        ],
   [-14.5054    ,   5.        ],
   [-14.33635   ,   5.        ],
   [-14.1707    ,   5.        ],
   [-13.8324    ,   5.        ],
   [-13.66605   ,   5.000121  ],
   [-13.50385   ,   5.000464  ],
   [-13.33785   ,   5.001173  ],
   [-13.1701    ,   5.002377  ],
   [-12.83478   ,   5.00674   ],
```

I need to iterate through all rows of the dataFrame allData and stretch the X,Y arrays so they are all 1000 rows in length (I think I need to interpolate to do this?). I want the trajectories to look the same after stretching/interpolation, just with more data points filling up the spaces.

I've tried using resampy and interp1d but I'm just struggling to figure it out.

Comment: for clarity: you expect these to be interpolated uniformly?  As in, all samples are expected to occur over the same total time duration at equal increments, or you have timestamps somewhere else?

Comment: also; can you give the `shape` and `dtype` values for the xy data?

Comment: Yes they can be expected to occur over the same total time duration. The actual arrays are varying lengths (sampled at 50Hz so around 2-18 seconds) but I need them all to be 1000 points in length (i.e., stretched to be 20 sec in length)

Comment: The xy data varies in shape but always only has two columns (X & Y). It ranges between approx 100-900 rows. The dtype is float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function takes each row and interpolates `N=1000` points for each x, y value in each row as requested:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

# gen dummy data:
_N = 20
data = []

for _ in range(_N):
    l = np.random.choice(np.arange(100, 900))
    xy = np.array([np.arange(l), np.arange(l)]).T + np.random.random(size=(l, 2))
    data.append([np.random.choice(np.arange(100000, 999999)), xy])
allData = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["participant", "data"])

# function that does the interpolation
def gen_records(arr, N=1000):
    # interpolate arr over `N` evenly spaced points
    min_val = np.min(arr)
    max_val = np.max(arr)

    t_orig = np.linspace(min_val, max_val, len(arr))
    t_interp = np.linspace(min_val, max_val, N)
    f = interp1d(x=t_orig, y=arr)
    interp_arr = f(t_interp)
    return interp_arr

# apply to dataframe    
allData["interp_data"] = allData.data.apply(
    lambda ser: np.array([gen_records(ser[:, 0]), gen_records(ser[:, 1])]).T
)
```

To note:

- if the full timespan of your sample data (rows) is different, this may be misleading, as the time increment of `interp_data` will not be the same
- you are storing nested arrays within each row of a df; this is not how pandas/numpy were intended to be used.  You would benefit from "flattening" this so each element is a single value.

For example, it would be easier to work with the data like:

```
df_x = allData.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.interp_data[:,0]), axis=1).T
col_dict = {idx: str(part) + "_x" for idx, part in zip(allData.index, allData.participant)}
df_x.rename(columns=col_dict, inplace=True)
df_y = allData.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.interp_data[:,1]), axis=1).T
col_dict = {idx: str(part) + "_y" for idx, part in zip(allData.index, allData.participant)}
df_y.rename(columns=col_dict, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df_x, df_y], axis=1)
df = df.sort_index(1)
```

preview:

```
       127877_x    127877_y    157700_x    157700_y    192204_x    192204_y  ...    743568_x    743568_y    805716_x    805716_y    805971_x    805971_y
0      0.090315    0.710476    0.992240    0.120537    0.552173    0.470253  ...    0.858416    0.206509    0.340299    0.182788    0.280935    0.998095
1      0.949895    1.661619    1.557746    1.009242    1.023637    1.072346  ...    0.977083    0.472867    0.630777    0.494193    1.417067    1.586117
2      2.344848    2.088494    2.053382    1.654844    1.495102    1.674438  ...    1.095750    0.739226    0.921255    0.805599    2.283156    2.184530
3      3.035018    2.977106    2.456115    1.977199    1.834009    2.194734  ...    1.214417    1.005584    1.259526    1.145122    2.891425    2.810716
4      3.650583    4.146497    3.280621    2.600666    2.108019    2.674983  ...    1.333084    1.271942    1.796585    1.601598    3.198264    3.511372
..          ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...  ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
995  844.979568  845.122972  634.268262  633.938912  427.674833  427.567986  ...  170.785379  170.618781  355.071745  355.069744  716.770732  716.554800
996  845.950312  845.685666  634.948427  634.520986  428.257304  428.351386  ...  171.069453  170.947405  355.400044  355.306856  717.315723  717.113295
997  846.831059  846.751367  635.483162  635.045098  428.803142  429.014094  ...  171.353527  171.276028  355.789927  355.801735  717.761773  717.753674
998  847.517356  848.121364  636.024521  635.743284  429.274156  429.430282  ...  171.637600  171.604652  356.194615  356.358587  718.339794  718.670332
```

your rows are times and each column is a `participant_x` or `participant_y` series.

Comment: Does exactly what I needed.

Comment: You mentioned that I shouldnt store nested arrays within each row of a df but I'm not entirely sure I understand - I need each row to contain the X,Y data for a single participant's trial. What is the best way to do this in a dataframe?

Comment: Also in your code comments you say "ser tinit -> tfin ", what does that mean?

Comment: it depends what you want to do with it, but a reasonable format might be columns like: `6432024_x`, `6432024_y`, etc.  This is generally how timeseries are represented, and opens up the pandas api (or numpy/scipy) for processing

Comment: Ok so I generally shouldnt  have a datraframe that mixes columns with single values and columns with long arrays?

Comment: better not to have nested/list-like data - flatten it into the df itself

Comment: To be explicit, I'll leave a note at the end of the soln